# applications of residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration

I want to know if the residue method is applicable to calculate the integral (which kind of contour?)
$$ \int_0^{+ \infty} \frac{\sin x }{1+x^2} dx. $$
We know that it is easy to calculate this integral if we replace $ \sin $ by $ \cos $ because of this function is even and then we can pass to the integral over $ ]- \infty,  + \infty[. $

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this integral has no known closed form. Using the special function called [*exponential integral*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) (which is proven to be a non-elementary function), we may write $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{e\operatorname{Ei}(-1)+e^{-1}\operatorname{Ei}(1)}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating after @Sangchul Lee 's comment, consider first
$$\frac{1}{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{(x+i)(x-i)}=\frac i 2\left(\frac 1{x+i} -\frac 1{x-i}\right)$$ and so
$$\int \frac{e^{ix}}{x^2+1} dx=\frac i 2\left(\int \frac {e^{ix}}{x+i}dx-\int \frac {e^{ix}}{x-i}dx\right)$$ For the first one, let $x+i=y$
$$\int \frac {e^{ix}}{x+i}dx=e\int \frac {e^{iy}}{y}dy=e \,\text{Ei}(i y)$$ Do the same for the second one and go back to $x$
$$\int \frac{e^{ix}}{x^2+1} dx=\frac i 2\left(e \,\text{Ei}(i x-1)-\frac{\text{Ei}(i x+1)}{e}\right)$$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x^2+1} dx=\frac{\pi }{2 e}+\frac i {2e}\left( \text{Ei}(1)-e^2 \text{Ei}(-1)\right)$$ and, unfortunately for you,
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2+1} dx=\frac{e\operatorname{Ei}(-1)+e^{-1}\operatorname{Ei}(1)}{2}\approx 0.646761$$

Comment: Thank you very much